# How can I set password for Redis cluster?

Tags: redis, passwords, cluster-computing

I'm trying to set password for my Redis cluster (3 masters, 3 slaves).
I have changed the /etc/redis/redis.conf configuration file on "requirepass" field, but when I log into the cluster i didn't get an error message (telling me to use password).

so, How can I set password for my Redis cluster?

thank you

Comment: Did you try restarting Redis so it picks up the config change? Not sure if Redis automatically loads the file when it is changed.

Comment: Yes I did.
not working unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Setting a slave to authenticate to a master
If your master has a password via requirepass, it's trivial to configure the slave to use that password in all sync operations.

**To do it on a running instance, use redis-cli and type:**

```
config set masterauth <password>
```

**To set it permanently, add this to your config file:**

```
masterauth <password>
```

Full info in: https://redis.io/topics/replication